# Get EV3's serial number from program

Tags: lego-mindstorms

I'm going to sell a lego mindstorms EV3 appliaction and I want to protect it. I'm not going to sell source code, only the compiled code so it's not possible to edit it. And to stop anyone from sharing it, I'd like to protect it somehow. The only way I found is to get EV3's s/n or any similar number that's uniquie in every EV3, it'd be easy. So, is this possible? Or are there any other ways to protect my program from sharing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a serial number that can be read via code. You could use the MAC address of the bluetooth module.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that. How can I read it from the program though?

Comment: How are you writing this program? Are you creating code for the LEGO VM? If the LEGO VM does not let you access it, you can't.